# flutter pageview wear os swipe right closes app

Tags: flutter, wear-os

I'm experiencing much frustration with a flutter pageview swipe right closing the app on wear os instead of changing to the previous page. It works fine on a mobile emulator and I can swipe back and forth between pages. But on the Wear OS emulator and debugging on my Pixel watch, I can swipe left to other pages, but a swipe right, no matter what page I'm on, closes the app instead of changing to the previous page.

It doesn't matter where I start my swipe. It briefly starts to bring the previous page and then immediately starts closing the app. I can't find any info on this behavior so I'm stuck.

I'm using a simple example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final pageController = PageController(
  initialPage: 0,
);

List<Widget> pages = [
  Container(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  Container(
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
];

return MaterialApp(
  home: PageView(
    children: pages,
  )
);
```

[image: Swipe left once]
Swiping left once

[image: Swipe left twice]
Swiping left twice

[image: Swipe right closes]
Swiping right closes

Comment: I see that I have the PageController in my code sample and it isn't referenced, that was a holdover from some other code I was testing.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found that if you add this line:

```
<item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
```

to android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml you can achieve the desired effect.